# How to quickly handle mobile-org pull errors?

Tags: linux, emacs, org-mode

According to the org-mode manual, here is what happens during a pull error, and how to handle it:

> Org moves all entries found in mobileorg.org1 and appends them to the file pointed to by the variable org-mobile-inbox-for-pull. Each captured entry and each editing event will be a top-level entry in the inbox file.
>   After moving the entries, Org will attempt to implement the changes made in MobileOrg. Some changes are applied directly and without user interaction. Examples are all changes to tags, TODO state, headline and body text that can be cleanly applied. Entries that have been flagged for further action will receive a tag :FLAGGED:, so that they can be easily found again. When there is a problem finding an entry or applying the change, the pointer entry will remain in the inbox and will be marked with an error message. You need to later resolve these issues by hand.
>       Org will then generate an agenda view with all flagged entries. The user should then go through these entries and do whatever actions are necessary. If a note has been stored while flagging an entry in MobileOrg, that note will be displayed in the echo area when the cursor is on the corresponding agenda line.
>
> Pressing `?` in that special agenda will display the full flagging note in another window and also push it onto the kill ring. So you could use `? z C-y C-c C-c` to store that flagging note as a normal note in the entry. Pressing `?` twice in succession will offer to remove the :FLAGGED: tag along with the recorded flagging note (which is stored in a property). In this way you indicate that the intended processing for this flagged entry is finished.
>
> If you are not able to process all flagged entries directly, you can always return to this agenda view2 using `C-c a ?`.

However, when I get a pull with errors, my inbox file (index.org) is automatically opened with the pull errata in a nice format (old/new, some tags, file descriptors, etc.), but nothing is marked :FLAGGED:. Hence, none of this works and I have to go through and apply fixes manually.

Example errata in generated file:

```
* Body was changed in MobileOrg and on the computer F(edit:body) [[olp:tracking.org:header1/header2][[2013-12-08 日 11:59]]]
** Old value
- Foo
** New value
- Bar


** End of edit
```

Comment: I recommend you'd post it to the mailing list of `org`.

Comment: I won't be viciously beaten for cross-posting?

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a cross-posting. I think you're better off taking the risk :)

Comment: @Dror it vanished into the sea of activity on the mailing list :(

Comment: I was luckier there... Sorry. I wish I could help more.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this problem, yeah, on Emacs 28.2 on 2023, just post here to help others bothered by this problem.

On my side it's a bug that only occurs when I edit the first node of an orgmode file, and there is no any other text before the first node, for instance:

```
* the very first node

some content, and try to edit this file on MobileOrg
```

And, an obvious workaround is to put some newlines before the first headline.